# SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with wordpress search

Tags: database, comments, search, errors, phpmyadmin

When I make a search on my site no posts are retrieved and through wordpress debug I get this error message:

WordPress database error: [Table 'theme_se.wp_comments' doesn't exist]

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_theme_se_posts.ID FROM wp_theme_se_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%paradox%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%paradox%') OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID AND comment_content LIKE '%paradox%' ) OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM wp_terms INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND object_id = wp_posts.ID AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%paradox%' ) ) AND wp_theme_se_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'referenser', 'partners', 'galleri') AND (wp_theme_se_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_theme_se_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_theme_se_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_theme_se_posts.post_title LIKE '%paradox%' DESC, wp_theme_se_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12

I have deleted all my plugins but it is still not working and the wp_comments table does exist when I view it through phpmyadmin

Comment: What is your database table prefix - both in phpmyadmin and in your wp-config.php? Did you change it at any time _after_ installing WordPress?

Comment: Not sure but in phpmyadmin it is wp_theme_se_ so for example wp_theme_se_posts . In wp_config file the table prefix is wp_ . And no I have not changed the table prefixes anywhere after WordPress installation :/

Comment: Now it works great! I removed a search optimizing function and fixed the prefixes and now it works great! :))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your database prefix settings are off-kilter.

Check the database prefix actually in use in your database, and make sure it's the same as the one in `wp-config.php`. Also make sure all of your WordPress-related tables have the same prefix.

You'll also need to search through your database, particularly in the _options table, as the previous database prefix will be hard coded in there in a few places.